# Seam JBoss Servlet injection

Tags: servlets, jboss, seam, seam2, seam-conversation

I am a beginner creating a SEAM (2.2) application with JBoss AS6

I am integrating the Paypal express checkout code which acts as an http servlet, this seems to work ok with the payments processing correctly by paypal, the problem is I cannot seem to inject my stateful backing beans into the servlet to verify the payment and update the database on my side. I have tried a variety of methods including the following...

```
@In PaymentBean paymentBean

PaymentBean paymentBean = (PaymentBean) Contexts.getConversationContext().get("PaymentBean")

paymentBean = ((PaymentBean)Component.getInstance("paymentBean"));
```

In each case I am left with a null pointer exception, I dont think its a problem with the bean as it wont even inject the messages files

As I have seen a lot of similar issues I am not even sure if this is possible with my setup? Is there some further configuration I am missing?

Can somebody suggest a solution, or a way to access my backing beans from the servlet?

Thanks

Comment: does PaymentBean have a @Name annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the answer to my question lives here...

http://seamframework.org/Documentation/ReplacingServletsWithSeamResources